# Show variable as a text in php

Tags: php, shell

i'm having trouble showing the text `ip4=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)` in PHP

```
$shpmtaserver .= "ip4=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)" . "\n";
```

Any ideas to do this ?

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't do anything except append to a string, but it should at least do that correctly. What exactly are you expecting to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `.` in front of `.=`. You would use that to append to an existing variable.

The follow code should work just fine.

```
$shpmtaserver = "ip4=$(/sbin/ip -o -4 addr list eth0 | awk '{print $4}' | cut -d/ -f1)" . "\n";

echo $shpmtaserver;
```